# Error deserializing a custom tuple in WCF

Tags: web-services, wcf, silverlight, serialization, deserialization

Below error while deserializing result set(tuple) in WCF function.

There was an error while trying to deserialize paramenter XXX. Please see InnerException for more details.

'System.Tuple' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.

Below is the tuple definition.

Public Class XXX
  Public Property aaa As New List(of Tuple(of bbb,ccc))
End class

Comment: What does the inner exception say, this does not provide enough information.

Comment: Can you post the de-serializing code?

Comment: Public Function EndXXX(ByVal result As System.IAsyncResult) As XXX Implements EndXXX
                Dim _args((0) - 1) As Object
                Dim _result As XXX = CType(MyBase.EndInvoke("XXX", _args, result), XXX)
                Return _result
            End Function

Answer (score 1):

Untimely, you need to make a class instead of using a Tuple. The exception says you cannot use a Tuple because A) It's not marked with the `DataContract` Attribute and B) Because it doesn't have a parameter-less constructor. So, a `Tuple<int,string>` cannot be set to a `new Tuple<int,string>();`

If the class you sent via WCF was like this...

```
public class MyClassToSendThroughWcf
{
    public tuple<int,string> MyData {get;set;} //The tuple here is problem, replace with the class below...
}
```

You could replace the type of "MyData" with a class that does the same thing like this...

```
public class MyClassToUseWithWcf
{
    public MyClassToUseWithWcf(){}

    public MyClassToUseWithWcf(int i, string s)
    {
        Item1 = i;
        Item2 = s;
    }

    public int Item1 {get;set;}
    public string Item2 {get;set;}
}
```

Now, both classes have default constructors, so it can be serialized. I suggest avoiding tuples anyway.

Comment: I did use the DataContract attribute for the class.

Comment: You probably added the attribute to the class that housed the tupel, but I don't think you can add the attribute to the tupel struct itself. The class I showed in this answer is a replacement for your tupel that will work with WCF.

Comment: I added some clarification to my answer.